# Android 2.3 browser - image doesn't appear

Tags: android-2.3-gingerbread, android-browser

When this page is viewed in Firefox on an Android 2.3 phone:

http://www.lmidev.com/sites/main/classlocator/index-mobile.html

a magnifying glass image appears in the 'Address or postcode' box (this is a 'submit' input button, with a background image applied).  However on the default Android browser, it doesn't appear.  Why is this, or how can I find out?  On another page in a different domain with code that seems to be identical, the image appears fine in the Android browser.

(I tried getting weinre to work for remote debugging, but haven't been able to get the server to connect when I browse to the site.  I've now removed the JavaScript used to connect to weinre)

Answer (score 0):

The background image for the submit button was being applied like this:

```
background: url("../images/mobile/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -61px -3px transparent;
```

For some reason, in the Android 2.3 browser, I needed to add the '!important' declaration to the style property:

```
background: url("../images/mobile/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -61px -3px transparent !important;
```

Best guess is that Android applies its own background for the submit button, that needs to be overriden.